# QProgressBar with QTableWidget stretched

Tags: qt, qtablewidget, qprogressbar

I'm trying to stretch `QProgressBar` to fill with `QTableWidgetItem`, I have not found any solution about this, do anyone know how? Thanks!

```
...
ui->tableWidget->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(QHeaderView::Stretch);
...
QProgressBar *bar = new QProgressBar(ui->tableWidget);
ui->tableWidget->setCellWidget(0, 0, bar);
```

What should I do to make `QProgressBar` to fit on `QTableWidgetItem`? My problem is related to [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23225).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, that blank area is where the % value will go. You can hide it with `bar->setTextVisible(false)`. You can also try to change its position with stylesheets.